# iOS TableView delay between adding new cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, delay

I'm working with UITableView and I want to add new items once at a time instead of adding them all at one time when there are multiple new items. Right now, my code is like this:

```
for rowNum in 0...(counter-1) {

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowNum, section: lastSection)], with: .fade)
    }   
 }
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Can you clarify "not working"? That may be why you did not get any answers (it also needs retagging, I will do that now).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but maybe I can help. While inserting new rows or sections, you need to use tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates(). Also, between these two functions, row numbers and the count of the array should be equal. Otherwise an error is thrown. Try this:

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.<yourArray>.append(<newElement>)
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.<yourArray>.count - 1, 
                                             section: lastSection)], with: .fade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Actually you do **not** *need to use tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates()*. You need it only for multiple **simultaneous** `insert/delete/move` operations. Apart from that it would defeat the main goal of the question.

Comment: Yes, actually you are right about update functions. Since I dont know why the code does not work, I tried to guess the potential problem. Then, the **inequality** between _data source_ and _indexPath_ can be the reason.